# Setting Environmental Variable in C via assignment

Tags: c, environment-variables

In my C program I can set environmental variable via.. `setenv`

However setenv only allows me to setup an environmental variable via a string.

Currently in my environment I have the below setup in my bash profile...

```
export MY_PASSWORD=`java -jar decrpytpassword $ENCRYPTED_PASS`
```

where decryptpassword is a Java executable jar file which accepts encrypted password and prints out decrypted password.

I want to do something similar in my C program where I will pass the encrypted password via a string and decrypt it.

Comment: Note that having your decrypted password in your environment is a major security risk.  Avoid it!  And you should usually avoid using backticks as shown: use `export MY_PASSWORD=$(java -jar decryptpassword "$ENCRYPTED_PASS")` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be:

1. Use `popen` to run the command and capture its output.
2. Read a string from that output (perhaps using `fgets`).
3. Put that new string in the environment using `setenv`.

P.S. If you use `fgets` in step 2, you may have to add a step 2a to strip the trailing `\n`.